# SoftwareAG webMethods EDI mapping question : How to map one record into Multiple records

Tags: mapping, edi, webmethods

I am trying to map one record into multiple records using webMethods Designer flow service.
1 row converted into several rows.
Please help me to wire webethods flow service to map the following using LOOP,REPEAT, MAP, etc.

SourceRecord
DateFields                                  TargetRecord
DT  ( Record initiator )( 1 .. 1 )      DTM  (Record initiator)( 1 .. many times)
OrderDate                                  DTM_01
SalesDate                                  DTM_02
ExpireDate

```
Sample Input data ( element delimiter "," and segment terminator newline)

DT,20200914,20200916,20230913   <-- where DT is record initiator "," is element separator 
                                    and orderDate = 20200914
                                        SalesDate = 20200916
                                        ExpireDate = 20230913

Desired Output Data ( multiple rows)  ( DTM is record initiator element delimiter "*" and segment terminator newline)
DTM*002*20200914   <-- 002 is qualifier for OrderDate
DTM*007*20200916   <-- 007 is the qualifier for SalesDate
DTM*036*20230913   <-- 036 is the qulifier for ExpireDate
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information. Do you have one string with one record of input data? Do you have a list of strings or a document list? Most likely the record comes from a flat file?
Is the output a string list or document list?

Anyway, the simple solution to your question (assuming one record) is to tokenize (using pub.string:tokenize) the input string and map it to output object using indices concatenating it with preset qualifiers:

[image]
[image]

Now you can build your string out of that string list using pub.string:makeString, using new line as separator (notice that cursor is on the second line):
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I would like to do edi mapping one record input to multiple records output
I have csv input file with one line content like 
                  
 DT,20200914,20200916,20230913 
 
 and I would like to see output file with 3 lines  content like 
 
DTM*002*20200914
DTM*007*20200916
DTM*036*20230913

Comment: In that case my example is more or less what you want as it requires a string (1 line) on the input and  generates a string (with 3 lines) on the output. Only a matter of writing that string to a file using a built in or custom service.